# How to transfer an .ai file from Adobe Draw to a different Adobe account?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-draw

I'm a graphic designer and I'm working with an artist who uses Adobe Draw (on an iPad), and does not have an Adobe subscription themselves.

I was wondering if it's possible for them to send their Draw file to my Illustrator, without them having to use Illustrator themselves?

I need to work with an editable file instead of a flat image, so I'm open to any options to make this happen for me without them needing their own access to Illustrator, if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There are two options for sharing in Draw. The first shares your entire project, including all the drawings within that project. This option only goes to Behance as a published project.

The second option shares individual drawings within a project. To access this option, you must first open a drawing and get into drawing mode. In this mode, you should see your drawing tools on the side and a header bar across the top. On that header bar is a share icon. Send To Illustrator/Photoshop should be options in the resulting popup that you see after tapping that icon.

Comment: If this sends to Illustrator/Photoshop, will it only be available on that person's Adobe Cloud? We have different accounts -- I need to get it from his cloud to mine, and he has no access to Illustrator himself.